# C and addition, integer first and later

Tags: c, imperative-programming

I'm come from Java, i want to improve my skill in coding and knowledge of how it's work in deep and i figure that the best language for this is C the mother of all. I'm very excited about how it work c but now please raise me a doubt. Why in C first code don't work and the second yes?

P.s.: I'll skip  few steps to speed the code and focus on problem. I'm study C99.

```
int a,b,c;
int sum = a+b+c;
print scanf ecc...
printf("%d", sum);
```

The result it will be -1234567 ecc..

And using this code it will work wonderful, this is the mean of a imperative programming?

```
int a,b,c;
int sum;
print scanf ecc...
sum = a+b+c;
printf("%d", sum);
```

Sorry for bad english is not my first language, i will improve also that :°D

Comment: `Why in C first code don't work and the second yes?` Because in the first one variables `a, b, c` are used uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not initialized in C, their values are *indeterminate*. Using an uninitialized local variable leads to *undefined behavior*.

C is also, exactly like Java, sequential in the absence of loops or gotos. Statements are executed from top to bottom so calling `scanf` to initialize a variable after you used it will not work. The previous operation will not be redone.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the first part of the code i.e.

```
     int a,b,c;
     int sum = a+b+c;
     print scanf ecc...
     printf("%d", sum);
```

it will first add the `a` ,`b` , `c`
and then will produce result with garbage value

while in second case

```
     int a,b,c;
     int sum;
     print scanf ecc...
     sum = a+b+c;
     printf("%d", sum);
```

it will read the values by using the scanf and then add those values so will not take the garbage value and produce a wonderful result